# When knitting an Rmarkdown Word doc, it opens as a read only file

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

When you knit a word doc with Rmarkdown, it automatically opens a Read Only window of the just created document. Is there a way to change it so this opened window is not Read Only? Currently I have to close it and then reopen the file to make edits. This isn't a big deal but it would be nice if I could skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is `read-only` only in the Preview pane. Exit and re-open the Word file outside of the Preview pane, and the `read-only` tag will be gone. Check the file properties in Windows explorer to verify.

Comment: Yes, the one that pops up is the only one that is read-only, but that is what I would like to see if there's a way to change. It becomes tedious to have to close that preview and open the word doc again every time I knit something. It would be better if the preview was not read-only, or if the preview didn't open up at all.